# How can I bypass rails server's restriction in regards to js runtimes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, node.js, ruby, webserver, puma

I am making a fairly large Rails webapp that will not be using any javascript in any form. Therefore, I didn't see the need to use nodejs/a js runtime (especially since I wish to be as security conscious as i can be- nodejs has some documented security issues). However, rails will not let me start the server unless I have a runtime installed. How can I bypass/get by this restriction?

Answer (score 0):

You may have to turn off the asset pipeline in rails. Try adding this to your `config/application.rb`:

```
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: Do you think this will have any negative effect on other rails dependencies?

Comment: Does your application compile sass?